# Best open source bug tracker with Mylyn support

Tags: bug-tracking, mylyn

I'm trying to determine which open source (or at least free) bug tracker works the best with Mylyn. My hope is to find something that "just works" with good Mylyn support.  I want to avoid lots of configuration and maintenance to get it going or keep it working with Mylyn.  Also, I'd like the interaction to support as many types of fields and data exchange as possible.

I've heard that Jira is the best one to use, but the project I'm working on is a private closed source venture, and the funds aren't there to pay for Jira. Same for FogBugz. I need a free solution for closed-source code. Possible options that I've heard of so far are Bugzilla, Mantis, Redmine, and Trac.  Is there a strong preference between these?  Are there other better solutions?

At this time, we're using SVN for source control, but may transition to GIT in the future.  Not sure if that matters, but if it does, I wanted to mention it.

The bug tracker will be installed and run on a linux VPS server with Apache and MySQL installed.  But it can be customized to run other software if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bugzilla, Mantis or Trac all work just fine with Mylyn. I would say that the best one supported is and probably will be Bugzilla, since eclipse people use it for their own bug tracking, and Bugzilla connector is developed by core Mylyn developers.

Comment: they're all good except for trac if you need multi project support.

Comment: We having a bit of trouble with Mylyn and Mantis with larger projects, plus there seem many small papercuts missing in the mantis connector like client side filter, correct username display, etc ..

Answer (score 3):

I have installed Redmine at home. I have it up at running with Mylyn in Eclipse too. I have used Bugzilla previously, but I think Redmine's interface is much cleaner and I especially like the roadmap feature.

Comment: I too selected Redmine. However, I'm no longer using Mylyn as I'm now using IDEA instead of eclipse.