# any agile free cross-platform project management/ALM tools with mylyn integration out there?

Tags: cross-platform, project-management, agile

Is there a solution I have missed? I would prefer a open source tool, not just a 1-5-developer free plan (so not BaseCamp, Mingle, Jira/Greenhopper). And it has to run on both windows and linux (so no ScrumDesk or TargetProcess). It has to support agile development process - user stories, iterations, point estimates, tasks etc.

What i really would love to have is a mylyn connector for agilefant. But agilefant has no public API, so it is not even possible to do anything about it AFAIK.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675295/what-is-the-best-connector-for-a-single-developer-to-store-mylyn-tasks-in-the-clo) and  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972371/best-open-source-bug-tracker-with-mylyn-support) about free bug tracking tools with mylyn integration, but what i am looking for is different as i would like a project management/ALM tool

Answer (score 2):

Your question intrigued me so I did a quick search. Haven't explored this yet, but did come across this:

[Comparing Open Source Agile Project Management Tools](http://olex.openlogic.com/wazi/2009/comparing-open-source-agile-project-management-tools/)

Comment: thank you, the comparison is a bit outdated by now, as agilefant 2 is out, but following the link to IceScrum i discovered that they have a mylyn connector by now. Thats the next thing to try for me.

Comment: yea, your question interested me so I looked around. I'm currently using versionone but it doesn't meet your criteria. Not sure if it support Mylyn either... Got this question bookmarked to see what others come up with.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Agilo](http://www.agile42.com/cms/pages/agilo/) (which is based on Trac) successfully in the past and it is supposed to integrate with Eclipse via Mylyn.

Comment: Thank you, Agilo looks nice. The freemium plan is acceptable. Ill definitely try the mylyn integration this week

Comment: I double-clicked on the upvote and now it is disabled unless you edit the answer :( sorry

Comment: Hey. That does look like a nice agile tool...

Comment: @Bryce It's a very decent tool when you need a ready to use all in one solution (wiki + VCS integration + ticket tracking + Scrum support). Perfect candidate to bootstrap something when there is not much in place.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda looks to me like Agilefant has a RESTful API now - [see here](http://www.agilefant.org/wiki/display/AEF/RESTful+API) - although the details aren't shown on the page.  You ought to be able to get what you need that way.

If you're thinking about writing a connector, you might already know about the [Mylyn integrator reference](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn_Integrator_Reference) and the [Mylyn integrators mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/mylyn-integrators).

Comment: Thank you, good to know they are doing something about it. The last thing i read was "no public API". I hope IceScrum is a good alternative as they already provide a mylyn connector.

Answer (score 1):

I belive that Redmine is the way to Go.

It is very powerful, Agile enabled, and easy to learn platform. I suggest you to give it a try, and you will just love it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Redmine can be customized to support user stories, tasks, product backlog items, sprint backlog items via its tracker and workflow features. The default out-of-the-box task structure is not 100% Scrum compatible. So we analyzed our needs and found out that Redmine was capable of supporting our needs. So nowadays we are converting our TFS shop to the old redmine-svn repo by using Bitnami's Redmine Stack and upgrading it. After that we will be buying easyredmine's on premises solution and their Resource Management plugin but these aren't necessary for our core requirements. Redmine itself is capable of supporting a Scrum methodology. You just need to analyze your needs and customize it accordingly.